# From $\mathsf{O}$ to $\mathsf{I}$ via $\infty$

Tags: soft-question, notation, terminology, math-history

The following is not true mathematics, but a little imaginary story about mathematical *symbols*. I wonder if there is - in parts - a *true* (etymological) story behind it.

**Once there was a symbol $\mathsf{O}$ for "nothing", and there was a symbol $\mathsf{I}$ for "something".**

(Switching to present tense:) Topologically, the symbol $\mathsf{O}$ is a circle (without ends), and the symbol $\mathsf{I}$ is a line segment (with two ends). Topologically, these two symbols cannot be continuously transformed into each other.

1. But the symbol $\mathsf{I}$ can be continuously transformed into a figure looking like $\omega$. This figure $\omega$ can be flipped *vertically*, and appropriately joint with its original looks like $\infty$.
2. On the other hand, the symbol $\mathsf{O}$ can be flipped *horizontally*, and appropriately joint with its original looks like $\infty$, too.
3. Finally, bending the ends of $\omega$ on and on, the figure $\infty$ is a *limit* of continuous transformations of $\mathsf{I}$.

My question is:

> (How) are these - at first sight only *somehow* related - mathematical symbols for
>
> - "nothing-ness" ($\mathsf{O}$),
> - "some-ness" ($\mathsf{I}$),
> - countable infinity ($\omega$), and
> - arbitrary infinity ($\infty$)
>
> *truly* - e.g. historically and/or etymologically -  related?

Comment: I feel that this is deviating way way off topic. The symbol $\infty$ was chosen long before $\omega$ was defined, and I am fairly certain the latter wasn't chosen by the fact that a rotation by $\pi$ radians and gluing on a copy with the same center of mass will result in a $\infty$-like symbol.

Comment: No, those four symbols are not historically or etymologically related.

Comment: John Wallis introduced $\infty$ for infinity in $1655$; his motivation is uncertain, but he may have taken it from an early form of the Roman numeral for $1000$. See [here](http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html) a bit over halfway down the page for a little more detail.

Comment: The use of a stroke to represent $1$ is ancient and cross-cultural. The earliest known antecedent of our $0$ is probably a simple dot in some early Indian inscriptions. The Maya symbol for zero, on the other hand, represents a shell of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such relation between these symbols, but if you enjoy messing with such things, here is a **challenge**:

Find the smallest set of symbols that can generate the entire English alphabet (where you are allowed to rotate and flip).

Here is a somewhat reasonable answer with $13$ symbols:

b, c, e, f, h, i, k, L, m, o, r, s, x.

For completeness, the equivalence classes are:

{a, e, g}, {b, d, p, q}, {c, n, u}, {f, t}, {h, y}, {i}, {J, r}, {k}, {L, v}, {m, w}, {o}, {s, z}, {x}.

Of course, the font needs to be rendered properly for this to work.

Comment: $g$ in the class of $a$ and $e$ (well, ok for this one, with the correct font as you said)? $a$ and $e$ not in the class of $b$, $d$, $p$ and $q$ ? And what about $h$ and $r$ ?

Comment: @arbautjc Flipping the $e$ horizontally ought to give a $g$. I have $h$ with $y$ by just rotating $180$ degrees; I have $r$ as $J$ similarly rotated.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought more "topologically" :-)